# Can we use more than one objects in ng-style for a single element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

In controller we have two ng-style objects.

```
$scope.rightpadding = {
    paddingRight : '11px'
}



 $scope.toppadding = {
    paddingTop : '7px'
}
```

We want to use both these in ng-style, some thing like this

Is not working.

It can't be like

$scope.style = {
  paddingRight : '11px',
  paddingTop : '7px'
}
How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one method which will create an object by combining the result from multiple methods & will set it to `ng-style` object.

Also `paddingRight` should be `padding-right` & `paddingTop` should be `padding-top`

**HTML**

```
ng-style="setStyle()"
```

**Code**

```
$scope.rightpadding = function() {
  return {
    'padding-right': '11px'
  };
}

$scope.toppadding = function() {
  return {
    'padding-top': '7px'
  };
}

$scope.setStyle = function() {
  var object = {};
  angular.extend(object, $scope.rightpadding())
  angular.extend(object, $scope.toppadding())
  return object;
}
```

Comment: can we use angular.extend ? 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: @ShrishShrivastava yes I've used the same..do you looked at my edit?

Comment: Yes now I have seen. I was searching it too. Thanks. Its perfect way to achieve our requirement.

Comment: @ShrishShrivastava do accept the answer..if does helped..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using angular.extend is good and its working too. But if we do not want to use it then here is another way

**Create a common method in scope**

```
$scope.margeStyleObj = function(objectList) {
    var obj = {};
    objectList.forEach(function(x) {
      for (var i in x)
        obj[i] = x[i];
    });
    return obj;
  }
```

**Then call from html**

```
<h5 ng-style="margeStyleObj([toppadding,rightpadding])">
```